# Merge two PDF files into one page with rotation and translation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I have two PDFs that I need to merge into a single one, 1 width by 2 height in dimension. If you've heard of a tent card, this is producing a tent card PDF.

I've got the following script that does the various pieces separately, but is not producing an actual PDF with the right rotation. Imagine a 5"x5" facet, producing a 5"x10" PDF, the top half upside-down:

```
-  -  -  -  -
|           |
|           |
|           |   < Upside-down "back"
|           |
|           |
-  -  -  -  -   < Imaginary line
|           |
|           |
|           |   < Right-side up "front
|           |
|           |
-  -  -  - -
```

Using PyPDF2, it seems like it would be easy, but while I've been able to get the pieces working (rotation, translation, back above front, double height by single width), I have not been able to get them all to work together.

The commented-out lines are other things I've tried, which seem to produce a blank top part of the page where "back" should be, with the "front" correctly displaying/orienting normally, only at the bottom of the x2 height `translated_page` outfile.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import PyPDF2

from PyPDF2.pdf import PageObject

front_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('front.pdf', 'rb'))
front = front_reader.getPage(0)

back_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('back.pdf', 'rb'))
back = back_reader.getPage(0)

tent_height = front.mediaBox.getHeight() + back.mediaBox.getHeight()

translated_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, back.mediaBox.getWidth(), tent_height)
# translated_page.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(back, 1, 0, front.mediaBox.getHeight())
# translated_page.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage(back, 180, 0, 0)
translated_page.mergeRotatedPage(back, 180)
translated_page.mergePage(front)

writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
writer.addPage(translated_page)

with open('out.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer.write(outfile)
```

Here are the files referenced above. What am I missing?

http://jf.dialogs.com/pdf-rotate-pypdf2.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved the transformation matrix that I was applying; basically, I was translating it off `0, 0` origin, which rotated it down into the bottom, left quadrant, with the mediabox taking up the top, right exclusively:

```
-x,  y | x,  y
---------------
-x, -y | x, -y
```

The following solved that problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import PyPDF2

from PyPDF2.pdf import PageObject

front_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('front2.pdf', 'rb'))
front = front_reader.getPage(0)

back_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('back2.pdf', 'rb'))
back = back_reader.getPage(0)

tent_width = front.mediaBox.getWidth()
tent_height = front.mediaBox.getHeight() + back.mediaBox.getHeight()
tent_rotate_offset = front.mediaBox.getHeight()

translated_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, tent_width, tent_height)
translated_page.mergeRotatedTranslatedPage(back, 180, tent_width / 2, tent_rotate_offset)
translated_page.mergePage(front)

writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
writer.addPage(translated_page)

with open('out.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer.write(outfile)
```

I'm not sure why it's half the width. That would put the x-origin before the transform at 4.25", which suggests the rotation itself is centered on the `front` page width dimensions and not the corner instead of a/the corner.